# Verwirrung um den nüchternen Zustand

Tags: difference, standard-german, adjective-ending

Ich halte mich für einen Muttersprachler und trotzdem bin ich am Ende. :-D

Heißt es

> Ein Erwachsener in nüchternem Zustand...

oder

> Ein Erwachsener im nüchternen Zustand...

?

Je länger ich drüber nachdenke, desto weniger weiß ich Bescheid. Nach meinem Sprachgefühl geht beides.

Meine laienhaften Überlegungen:

Ausgeschrieben heißt es

> Ein Erwachsener in einem nüchternen Zustand

"im" = "in einem". Für diese Version würde auch das Sprichwort "m vor n" passen, was ich im Hinterkopf habe. Allerdings würde ich fragen "in wem oder was ist der Erwachsene"? Also Dativ. Also "in nüchternem".
Meine Vermutung: Grammatikalisch geht beides, weil man gruppieren kann, wie man möchte:

- (in einem) nüchternen Zustand --> im nüchternen Zustand
- in (einem nüchternen) Zustand --> in nüchternem Zustand

Bin ich auf dem Holzweg? Wie heißt es richtig? Falls beides geht, was sind die (unterschwelligen) Unterschiede? Gilt die Aussage auch mit bestimmtem Artikel für "in DEM nüchternen Zustand"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Der Unterschied zwischen beiden Formulierungen, die beide richtig sind, liegt gerade  darin, dass "im" die Verkürzung von "in dem" ist, aber "in [nüchterne]m" die Verkürzung von "in einem [nüchterne]n".

> "im nüchternen Zustand" = "in dem nüchternen Zustand"
> "in nüchternem Zustand" = "in einem nüchternen Zustand"

In diesem Beispiel macht das natürlich keinen Unterschied, und der Unterschied ist heutzutage sowieso etwas verwaschen, vielleicht weil man über eine so schwer hörbare Differenzierung nichts Wichtiges ausdrücken will. Er wird aber klarer, wenn man ein Beispiel nimmt, in dem es eine Rolle spielt, ob der Artikel bestimmt ist oder unbestimmt:

> "Bei warmem Wetter fährt sie [immer] mit dem Rad zur Arbeit." -> Bei einem warmen Wetter ...
> "Beim warmen Wetter fährt sie [heute] mit dem Rad zur Arbeit." -> Bei dem warmen Wetter ....

Answer (score 0):

Man kann sagen "In dem nüchternen Zustand" oder auch "In nüchternem Zustand". Das Dativ-"m" wird sozusagen vom Wort "dem" übernommen, falls man das Wort mit einbaut; dadurch fällt es bei "nüchternen" weg. Ein doppelt vorkommendes "m" ist nicht möglich.

"Im" ist eigentlich wie eine Abkürzung für "In dem". Du kannst also wahlweise zu "In dem nüchternen Zustand" auch "Im nüchternen Zustand" sagen.

Somit gibt es all diese richtigen Möglichkeiten.

Comment: Ok, das Dativ-m kann also sozusagen durchgereicht werden, von "nüchternem" zu "dem" und dann zu "im". Dann bleibt bei mir noch die Frage: Was ist an "Ein Erwachsener in vollem Haus..." (falsch) und "ein Erwachsener im vollen Haus..." (richtig) anders? Hier ist der Fall klar, denn das Dativ-m darf nicht beim Adjektiv stehen. Ist das nicht genau dieselbe Konstellation?

Comment: "Vor vollem Haus auftreten" geht, "In vollem Haus auftreten" geht nicht. Offenbar darf das m nicht immer bis zum "in" durchgereicht werden, weil sonst der Sinn verloren geht. Es sieht so aus, als ob es für Zustände zum "in" durchreichbar ist, für Ortsangaben aber nicht.

Comment: Die Antwort ist sehr unklar; weder eine Antwort darauf gegeben, was jetzt korrekt ist, was etwaige Bedeutungsunterschiede sind, noch wird irgendeine Art von grammatischer Erklärung gegeben ("das m wird durchgereicht", zähle ich nicht als solche). Daher gebe ich hier -1

Comment: In jeder Antwort auf die Frage sollte eigentlich irgendwo "indefiniter" oder "unbestimmter" Artikel vorkommen, was leider in den beiden vorliegenden nicht der Fall ist.